# From complex to polar

Tags: complex-numbers, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, polar-coordinates

In a scientific paper, the authors express the following eigenvector in the polar form
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left\{0,\frac{i \sqrt{a^2+b^2}}{a+i b},1,0\right\}$$
to take the form:
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left\{0,e^{i \theta },1,0\right\}$$
where $\theta =\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)$. Can I know how they did this?

Comment: References from the article?

Comment: @user326159 "Thermal entanglement in the anisotropic Heisenberg XXZ model with the Dzyaloshinskii-Moriyainteraction"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\tan\theta=a/b$, then

$$
\sin\theta=\frac{a}{a^2+b^2}\\
\cos\theta=\frac{b}{a^2+b^2}
$$

Now,

$$i\frac{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}{a+ib}=i\frac{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}(a-ib)}{a^2+b^2}\\
=i\frac{a-ib}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\\
=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta=e^{i\theta}
$$

Comment: @CyeWalsman  What about the negative sign that changed its position in the two equations?

Comment: Sorry, I can't answer that question and the cited paper is outside of my areas of expertise.

Comment: @CyeWalsman  By comparing the results of the aforementioned research with other research, I believe that there was a written error, so I edited my question.